# Java XML creates closing xml statement but no opening

Tags: java, xml, file-io, nodes, xmldocument

I have a program that creates an xml doc.

the filename is unimportant here because the file does get created successfully
the arraylist of entries contains a Unique identifier and a hashmap of
elements + values.  the elements are as follows: world, name, location, type and data
all these values are strings and the only one that would ever be blank/null is data
my problem is that the xml file adds all the fields as required with the exception 
of the data field.  it leaves me with an unopened node . actual result:

```
<NPC>
    <NPC:0>
        <name>
            the_name
        </name>
        <data/>  <---- this line should have the string "null"
        <loc>
            2529.1294962948955:
            69.0:
            951.2612160649056
        </loc>
        <type>
            Quest
        </type>
        <world>
            world
        </world>
    </NPC:0>
</NPC>
```

My method for creating the xml file.

```
public void updateXML(String fileName, ArrayList<XMLEntry> entries)
{
    File file = getFileByName(fileName);

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory bFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder b = bFac.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = b.parse(file);

        for(int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++)
        {
            XMLEntry entry = entries.get(i);

            Node entry_node = doc.getElementsByTagName(entry.getName()).item(0);

            if(entry_node == null)
            {
                Element node = doc.createElement(entry.getName());
                doc.getFirstChild().appendChild(node);
                entry_node = doc.getElementsByTagName(entry.getName()).item(0);
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> attributes : entry.getAttributes().entrySet())
            {
                NamedNodeMap xml_attributes = entry_node.getAttributes();
                Node attribute = xml_attributes.getNamedItem(attributes.getKey());
                if(attribute == null)
                {
                    if(attributes.getValue() != "" || attributes.getValue() != null)
                    {
                        Element new_xml_attribute = doc.createElement(attributes.getKey());
                        new_xml_attribute.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(attributes.getValue()));
                        entry_node.appendChild(new_xml_attribute);
                    } else {
                        Element new_xml_attribute = doc.createElement(attributes.getKey());
                        new_xml_attribute.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("null"));
                        entry_node.appendChild(new_xml_attribute);
                    }
                } else {
                    attribute.setTextContent(attributes.getValue());
                }

                TransformerFactory tFac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer ts = tFac.newTransformer();
                DOMSource src = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
                ts.transform(src, result);
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    } catch (TransformerException e1) {
    } catch (IOException e2) {
    } catch (SAXException e3) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your <data/> element is an empty element which means it has no content at all, so your code is OK. Here you can look at empty element more --> http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_empty.asp

Comment: I hesitate to recommend w3schools.com for anything XML-related. I've spent a bit too much time over the years correcting their erroneous statements. However, yes, this is an empty element.

Comment: This line does not do what you think it does: `if(attributes.getValue() != "" || attributes.getValue() != null)`

Comment: Aside from using reference equality to test a string (use `.equals()`), the two terms are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <data/>  <---- this line should have the string "null"
```

That isn't an XML close-element tag (which would be `</data>`). It's an XML empty-element tag, which combines open and close into a single piece of markup. It is semantically *identical* to `<data></data>`.

Despite your expectations, it would appear that the empty `<data/>` element is not being created by the path with the literal "null". Drop a printout into that code, or run it in the debugger, to confirm this. Then use the debugger, or drop in additional printouts as necessary, to figure out why.

Comment: no its not a string object of null it is literal null as in n+u+l+l

Comment: Comment in the example says (_this line should have the string "null"_). Ergo, the line which produces that text node is not being hit. (_new_xml_attribute.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("null"));_) Ergo, the conditional is doing the wrong thing. kdgregory's comment above is probably why.